# Why does my shortcut suggestion intent crash whenever I start the activity?

Tags: android, app-actions

This code is practically being copied from https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/in-app-promo-sdk and it still isn't working does anyone know why this isn't working for me?

```
            val feature: HashMap<String, Any?> = HashMap()
            feature["@type"] = "MenuItem"
            feature["@context"] = "http://schema.googleapis.com"
            feature["name"] = "signal on"

            val appShortcutIntent = AppShortcutIntent.builder()
                .setIntentName("actions.intent.ORDER_MENU_ITEM")
                .setPackageName("com.app.package")
                .setIntentParamName("menuItem")
                .setIntentParamValue(feature)
                .build()
            shortcutsClient.lookupShortcut(appShortcutIntent)
                .addOnSuccessListener { shortcutLookupResult ->
                    if (shortcutLookupResult.isShortcutPresent) {
                        shortcutsClient.createShortcutSettingsIntent().addOnSuccessListener { intent ->
                            requireActivity().startActivity(intent)
                        }
                        return@addOnSuccessListener
                    }
                    val signalShortcut = AppShortcutSuggestion.builder()
                        .setAppShortcutIntent(appShortcutIntent)
                        .setCommand("signal on")
                        .build()
                    shortcutsClient.createShortcutSuggestionIntent(signalShortcut).addOnSuccessListener { intent ->
                        requireActivity().startActivity(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))
                    }
                }
```

Comment: An error message or stack trace would make it easier for people to give you an informed response.

Comment: @Shawn I totally agree maybe I'm crazy but as far I could see there was no error message in the console at the very least

Comment: Try adding a failure listener `.addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.e("failure", e)}` after the `.addSuccessListener`.  The documentation makes it sound like it eats the error if you haven't defined a callback to handle it.

Comment: @Shawn yeah oddly enough that still doesn't do anything for me I'm not even getting an exception in the failure listener. I think this is because it's successful in creating the shortcut suggestion intent and for some odd reason when the activity pops up it immediately gets dismissed.

Comment: Interesting, are you able to set a breakpoint or a log statement in all 3 success listeners and make sure they are being executed?

Comment: I think this is a bug. I have raised a bug with Google developers. 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201790858